# Connect HmailServer whith PHP imap

Tags: php, routes, imap, windows-server-2012, hmail-server

I am having two virtual machine:
The first is for `php pages` and `web access`.
The second one contains a `hmailServer`.

Both are situated in a production environnement and can be accessed via internet and also via local network.

The problem is when i use `imap_open` in PHP to connect to `hmailserver` via `imap`, the time to execute is not stable, from `300 ms` to over `4 seconds`.

What do you think the problem is

An example

```
$p=imap_open("ip}INBOX","emailadress","password");
var_dump($p);
imap_close($p);
```

When i ran this code from an external server, it works and takes always about 300ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
The local ip address causes the problem and i don't know the reason.
I works well when i used the public ip